# Inserting table creates page break in SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting, report, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am creating SSRS Report using Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder 3.0.

I am having some page-break related problems. Whenever I insert a table in my report, it generates a page break at the end of the table.

Is there any way I can have this page break not generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't really know why, but this worked for me:

Remove page header and footer, and put header/footer content in body itself (but this is not something you can do if your report has more than one page).

Answer (score 0):

This is one check to make.   In the tablix properties, find the Pagebreak - disabled property and see if it's set to "False."  (If it is, set it to "True".)

Comment: Tried that... doesn't seem to help

Comment: You've also checked the settings for "page break after group" then I suppose.  I belive that's a report settting.